# Updating a dict attrib from an extended class updates the base class. Why?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, extends

```
>>> class Test(object):
...   test = {}
... 
>>> class Test2(Test):
...   pass
... 
>>> Test2.test.update({1:2})
>>> Test.test
{1: 2}
>>>
```

I was expecting {}. Happens also with old style classes.

Comment: Care to explin why would you explain anything different? Where would the Test2 instance of the "test" class attribute come from? Pure magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing odd with how `update` works. The point is that `test` is a [class attribute](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects), and class attributes are shared between classes, (untill someone rebinds `test` to something else).

Take a look at this IDE session:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     test = {}
... 
>>> class Test2(Test):
...     pass
... 
>>> id(Test.test)
32424144
>>> id(Test2.test)
32424144
>>> Test.test.update({1:2})
>>> Test2.test
{1: 2}
>>> Test2.test = {}
>>> id(Test2.test)
32424480
>>> Test.test
{1: 2}
>>> Test2.test
{}
>>> del Test2.test
>>> Test2.test
{1: 2}
```

For further informations on how class attributes works look at [Data Model Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) under Classes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 2 underscores to activate the class/attribute munging

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     __test = {}
...
>>> class Test2(Test):
...     pass
...
>>> Test2.__test.update({1:2})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Test2' has no attribute '__test'
```

Because of the attribute munging the attribute can be found at `Test2._Test__test` instead

If you want all the subclasses to automatically get their own `__test` attribute you can use a metaclass for `Test`

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I wasn't really trying to hide the attribute.

Comment: Setting the attribute itself doesn't update the base class. There's something odd with the update method of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test2.test.update({1:2})
```

This updates you base class Test attribute, which was inherited by Test2.

If you want want each of them to have their own dict, do:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     test = {}
... 
>>> class Test2(Test):
...     test = {}
... 
>>> Test2.test.update({1:2})
>>> Test.test
{}
>>>
```

Python has a feature which i like very much: data inheritance, which you just have seen in action.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of references. Take for example:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...   val = 1
... 
>>> class Test2(Test):
...   pass
... 
>>> Test2.val = 2
>>> Test.val
1
```

Here for the subclass val is reassigned to 2.

For lists and dictionaries both refer to the same object and any update/append will be visible in superclass. If you however reasign:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...   test = {}
... 
>>> class Test2(Test):
...   pass
... 
>>> Test2.test = {1:2}
>>> Test.test
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because they are the same object. More accurately, `Test2.test` is a way of accessing the same thing that `Test.test` does, because, when it is not found locally, it is looked up in the superclass.

I don't understand why would you expect any differently. (It doesn't work the way you're expecting in any other languages I can think of, either.)